# Prove that a bounded operator $A$ on Banach space is invertible (bijective) if $\left\|I - A\right\| < 1 $ holds?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

I can't seem to make any progress with the following problem:

If $ A $ is a bounded operator on Banach space $ X $ and if $ \lVert I - A \rVert < 1 $, prove that $ A $ is invertible/bijective.

This seems to be a known result, but I wasn't able to found a source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:
Use the real number analogue to gain some intuition: If $|x|<1$, then
$$\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n.$$

---

Set $B:=I-A$. Then $A=I-B$, so our intuition says that
$$ ``\ A^{-1} = \frac{1}{I-B} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty B^n.\ "$$
(Quotes in the above expression are there to indicate that it is nonsense. I include the expression anyway because sometimes nonsense can help us prove things.)

Now show that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \|B^n\|<\infty$. Since the space of bounded operators on a Banach space is complete, this implies that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty B^n$ converges in $X$. Then show that $(I-B)(\sum_{n=0}^\infty B^n)=(\sum_{n=0}^\infty B^n)(I-B)=I$, which will complete the proof that $A$ is invertible and
$$
A^{-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (I-A)^n.
$$

Comment: Thank you! I now understand every part of this version of the proof, except for the first one - I can't seem to find a reasonable way to prove that $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty ||B^n|| < \infty $. I've tried to look how $ B^n $ looks like for "small" $ n $ and to see what happens with the norm there, but without result.

Comment: Since $\|B\|<1$ we have
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\|B^n\|\leq\sum_{n=0}^\infty\|B\|^n = \frac{1}{1-\|B\|} < \infty.
$$
So the real number analogue can be useful outside providing intuition. Also, this gives us the estimate
$$
\|A^{-1}\| \leq \frac{1}{1-\|I-A\|}.
$$

Comment: I'm stupid. :) Thank you very much and sorry for bothering, the first hint should've been enough!

Answer (score 1):

For another approach that avoids series expansions, and gives a more general result, note that it suffices to show that $A$ and $A^*$ are bounded below.

So, suppose that $A$ is $\text{any}$ linear operator, and $B$ is an invertible linear operator such that

$\left \| A-B \right \|\cdot \left \| B^{-1} \right \|<1.$ Then,

$\left ( \left \| B^{-1} \right \| \right )^{-1}\cdot \left \| x \right \|=\left ( \left \| B^{-1} \right \| \right )^{-1}\cdot \left \|B^{-1}\cdot Bx \right \|\le \left \| Bx \right \|\le\\  \left \| \left ( A-B \right )x \right \|+\left \| Ax \right \| \le \left \| A-B \right \|\cdot \left \| x \right \|+\left \| Ax \right \|\Rightarrow \\ \left \| Ax \right \|\ge \left ( \left ( \left \| B^{-1} \right \| \right )^{-1}-\left \| A-B \right \| \right )\cdot \left \| x \right \|>\left \| x \right \|,\ $

from which we conclude that $A$ is bounded below.

But, $\left \| \left ( A-B \right )^{*}y^{*} \right \|\le \left \| A-B \right \|\cdot \left \| y^{*} \right \|$ and similarly for $(B^{-1})^{*}$ so that

$\left \| A^*-B^* \right \|\cdot \left \| (B^{-1})^* \right \|<1$ and so the same calculation as above shows that $A^*$ is also bounded below.

Comment: How does the result follow from injectivity if we aren't working in a finite-dimensional space?

Comment: @Johnstone23 quite right. But the same argument works for the adjoint and that is enough I guess.